# Inno Setup - How to display a message after installation is cancelled

Tags: inno-setup

How to display a message after an installation is completely cancelled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor the [`CurStepChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged). If the last step ever started is the `ssInstall` and you never get to the `ssPostInstall`, let alone `ssDone`, the installation was most probably aborted. In that case, display the message in the [`DeinitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=DeinitializeSetup).

```pascal
[Code]

var
  LastStep: TSetupStep;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  Log(Format('Step: %d', [CurStep]));
  LastStep := CurStep;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  { Installation started, but never finished => It must have been cancelled. } 
  if LastStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    MsgBox('The installation was successfully aborted.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```